# write file using formatter class

Tags: java, file, io

Actually Its the first time I am writing to a file in java using the formatter class, I am getting error in my file path and the error is wrong sequence!

Here is the piece of code I have tried to write:

```
package fileManipulation;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class fileReading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Formatter Outfile=new Formatter("\F:\Users\User\Desktop\OOSD\Semester Two\Student.txt");

        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in creating file!");
        }
        catch(SecurityException se)
        {
                System.out.println("User have permission to edit file!");
            }
        }
        Outfile.format("%s NAme , %d Salary");
        Outfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the error?

Comment: The problem you've got has nothing to do with `Formatter` - your code has an invalid string literal. You need to escape backslashes, and you probably don't want the leading backslash at all.

Comment: Invalid escape sequence :/

Comment: okay i will try escaping the back slashes

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is the invalid try-catch curly brackets. There should be a closing curly bracket (`}`) after `Formatter Outfile=new Formatter...`.